# What is the category of "What is the difference between milk (simple) and milk drink?"

Tags: discussion

As per the help-center under what category does the question [What is the difference between milk (simple) and milk drink?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/68531/21743) come under?

i.e.:

- Cooking & food preparation methods
- Kitchen equipment
- Food handling and storage
- Ingredient selection and use
- Recipe comprehension, improvement, and repairs

I was a bit doubtful but found similar question so posted it anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ingredient selection and use" is intended to cover things like this; the differences between two versions of an ingredient are part of how you select it.

It's hard to be that concise without leaving it a little ambiguous, but the idea is that we take questions about ingredients in a culinary context, for example:

- how to select an ingredient (ripe fruit, fresh vegetables)
- about attributes of an ingredient (descriptions or differences)
- how to prepare an ingredient (peeling, basic cooking techniques)

But you can't ask about things outside culinary topics, for example:

- how to grow an ingredient, though there is [Gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) for that
- how to eat an ingredient
- health/nutrition of an ingredient

(these lists are not meant to be exhaustive either)